python webapp using django and mongodb
I am working on a web app for a printing shop using django and mongodb. When migrating, my migration file changed and I got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\double_two_Print\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\double_two_Print\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 196, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 361, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 329, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 89, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 93, in state_forwards
    state.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\shamz\OneDrive\Desktop\shobi\double2_Project\shoaiba\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 248, in add_field
    self.models[model_key].fields[name] = field
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: ('products', 'product')


What does it mean?
I tried to migrate my file, it shows django's problem.

Possible typo in database/table/column names.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think you should clear all your migrations (enter database delete all sessions, tables, django_migrations) and delete in folder migrations. And after that execute

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

hope that these small hints will save your time.
